# How to correctly run gradle test task?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I try to build my project with gradle when I run gradle test from Intellij Idea everything is fine - all tests are passed but when I do the same operation from command line using command `gradle test` some unit tests failed. That is my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'myProjectName'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "my_repo_url"
    }
    maven {
        url "my_repo_url"
        credentials {
            username = System.getenv("MVN_USER")
            password = System.getenv("MVN_PASS")
        }
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {

    compile ('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.0.1')
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.7'

    compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.0.5.RELEASE') {
        exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }

    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-schemas', version: '4.0.1'

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.0.1.RELEASE')
    testCompile('com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path')
    testCompile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    testCompile group: 'pl.pragmatists', name: 'JUnitParams', version: '1.1.1'

    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.9.4'

}
```

and there is my junit test class:

```
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void testSimpleIfParsing() throws IOException {
        String complicatedStructure = "testString";
        IfTemplateElement MyClass = new MyClass(
                complicatedStructure // This variable NOT null, but I have NullPointerException
        );
        Object response = MyClass.evaluate();
        Assert.assertNotNull( response );
    }
}
```

and `MyClass` constructor:

```
public class MyClass {
public MyClass( String s ) {

        s = s.substring( 0, 5 );    // there I have NullPointerException.

    }
}
```

Exception:

```
com.mypackage.MyTest > testSimpleIfParsing FAILED
    java.lang.NullPointerException at MyTest.java:28
```

but if in the `MyClass` in the constructor I insert `System.out.println(s)` all tests passed in both cases (from CLI and Intellij Idea).

Can anyone help me what is goin on? 
Where I mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds strange.

I suggested that you will try to debug the UT with intelij and after that try with gradle.

How to change the unit test runner in inteliJ?

Go to settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > Runner

[image]